# Query to know who paid more than 10k

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, select

I have a table with payment informations, like this:

```
ID COSTUMER_ID DATEPAID     AMOUNT
1    1        2012-01-01      50
2    1        2012-02-01      100
3    1        2012-03-01      70
4    2        2012-03-01     6000
4    2        2012-09-01     3000
4    2        2014-04-01     8000
5    3        2013-03-01     9000
6    3        2013-08-01     3000
```

etc.
I need to know wich costumers paid more than 10k in a 12 months period. (in the exemple, only costumer 3 fits). Don't mind when, the only criteria is SUM(AMOUNT) > 10000 in any 12 consecutive months combination.

But i'm stuck on it. Any ideas?
I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You should give us a more instructive example., e.g.. 2014-03-01 instead of 2014-04-01 in the 5th row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is do a select back to the table and sum the rows before the row, and then use that as an inner query to be able to use the sum in the where clause, something like this:

```
select *
from (
  select
    P1.ID,
    P1.CUSTOMER_ID,
    P1.DATEPAID,
    (select sum(P2.AMOUNT) 
      from PAYMENT P2 
      where P1.CUSTOMER_ID = P2.CUSTOMER_ID and 
      P2.DATEPAID <= P1.DATEPAID and 
      P2.DATEPAID >= dateadd(month, -12, P1.DATEPAID)) as PAID12M
  from
    PAYMENT P1
) X
where PAID12M > 10000
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51e50/1).

This will return all the rows where the criteria matches, if you need only customer_id or first row or something like that, you'll have to make the outer query a little bit more complex.

Comment: If you have a lot of data, you may want to add an appropriate index (e.g., something like "ALTER TABLE payment ADD UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([CUSTOMER_ID], [DATEPAID])" in that fiddle) so that the correlated subquery is able to use a seek rather than scanning the full data set.

Comment: If I get the oldest date of each COSTUMER_ID, I get the first date that this person paid more than 30k. Nice sulution, runs fast (5s. for  26k registers).

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT COSTUMER_ID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS Total 
FROM TableName
WHERE DATEPAID BETWEEN '20120101' AND '20121231'
GROUP BY COSTUMER_ID
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) >10000
```

Comment: This is a specific date range, not a consecutive 12 month period

Comment: wrong, he said 'any consecutive months combination'

Comment: Have to be in any 12 consecutive months combination. If I have to insert all date combinations, that's not going to work.